# как сделать так чтобы телеграмм бот работал после ошибки?

Tags: python, telegram-bot

Код рабочий и работает всё как нужно до одного момента. Если человек перейдет по ссылке, то он получит из ссылки `data`, которая уже отправится в ссылку в коде, но если после этого человек опять введет команду `/start`, то выдает ошибку и весь бот отключается. Как сделать так, чтобы после этого он работал?

```
import telebot
import config

bot = telebot.TeleBot(config.TOKEN)

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def handle_start(message):
    bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'https://recca.me/' + message.text.split()[1])
    
bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете использовать конструкцию try-catch для обработки исключений

Пример кода ниже:

```
def handle_start(message):
    try:
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'https://recca.me/' + message.text.split()[1])
        # Если тут произойдет ошибка - сработает блок except
    except:
        # Тут вы можете обработать исключение
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Что-то пошло не так")
```